# Python script to call api and return json output

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to call a API/Url that returns a output in Json , But i am getting below error. Can someone help whats the issue about.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import requests
import sys
import json
newlist=[]
with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:80/status.json', json=[{{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }}])
        try:
            print("Response: HTTP {} {}".format(resp.statuscode, resp.content)
        finally:
            print("INVALID JSON FOR WEBSITE: {}".format(line.strip()))
            f.close()
```

Comment: There is no *below error*. Please add the stack-trace, logs etc/

Comment: You're assigning `r` but using `resp`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Your JSON has too many `{}`. `[{{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }}]` should be `[{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }]`. And if you expect something to fill in the `{0}`, etc. placeholders, that won't happen.

Comment: @Barmar sorry i copied from the post while googling

Comment: ./status.py
  File "./status.py", line 11
    finally:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python3.6
import requests
import sys
import json
newlist=[]
with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        resp = requests.post('http://localhost:80/status.json', json=[{{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }}])
        try:
            print("Response: HTTP {} {}".format(resp.statuscode, resp.content)
        finally:
            print("INVALID JSON FOR WEBSITE: {}".format(line.strip()))
            f.close()

Comment: Edit the FULL stack traceback/error message into your question so it is possible to see the code of the line that causes the error. I.e. which is line 11?

Comment: If you paste the error message in, we'll be able to see what the `^` points to.

Comment: You have a missing `)` on the first `print` line.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I corrected it and getting a diffrent error               
     ./status.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.8) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./status.py", line 8, in <module>
    resp = requests.post('http://localhost:80/status.json', json=[{{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }}])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Please provide the entire error message(s) as well as a [mcve], in your post itself and not as a comment. I can see at least two confusing/problematic things in the code.